# Filtering/mapping elements from one set based on certain joint conditions on the first and a second set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck in writing a mathematical expression for the following.

My code iterates over a set of elements $A$ and each element in $A$ has three parameters $x$, $y$, $z$. I have another set of elements $B$ which also has the same three parameters, but of course, with different values. Now for each element in $A$, I am filtering elements from $B$ by comparing the constitutive parameters with a threshold, e.g.,

1. $x_A$ (first element and iterates)- $x_B$ (all elements) $\le$ $\Delta x$
2. $y_A$ (first element and iterates)- $y_B$ (all elements) $\le$ $\Delta y$
3. $z_A$ (first element and iterates)- $z_B$ (all elements) $\le$ $\Delta z$

Please, I need help as I am not able to write a suitable expression for this and already spent a lot of time on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$C = \{\langle x, y, z \rangle \in B \ |\ \forall \langle x_A, y_A, z_A \rangle \in A \ [ (x - x_A \leq \Delta x) \ \land\  (y - y_A \leq \Delta y) \ \land \ (z - z_A \leq \Delta z)]\}$